# Unregister mapping in HandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write my custom `HandlerMapping` class. To do that, I've extended `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` class To register mappings I'm using `registerHandler` method. Is there any simple way to unregister mapping while an application is running? `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` unfortunately not provide any public method for that.

I found a ticket [[SPR-11541]](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11541) that's cover mentioned feature but I can't find the implementation.

Comment: I'm entirely not sure what your custom needs are but why not use the other variant AbstractHandlerMethodMapping and extend, which has the public register/unregister methods.

Comment: I want to make dynamic mappings like in Sling, but using Spring Framework.

Answer (score 2):

It's introduced in Spring 4.2 as stated [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_web_improvements_2) (5th bullet point)

As you can see there is no `unregisterMapping` method here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.html

but there is one here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.html#unregisterMapping-T-

Which version do you use?

Comment: I don't know why I doesn't see it before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty by do this if you just have a handler matching a pattern like: ("stuff/**")
Once you intercept this then check the HttpServletRequest getRequestURL() and treat it however you see fit.

```
RequestMapping("/stuf/**")
public String test(HttpServletRequest request)
{
   StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
   // Do whatever you want with the url now
}
```

Comment: Personally I don't like dynamic urls, much rather use request parameters but there are legitimate reasons to do this, I see it done allot with users accounts or sort of websites within a website, just like if you click on your SO profile.